# How to connect a full wave bridge rectifier to an electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

When connecting a bridge rectifier to a polarized capacitor, does plus from the bridge rectifier go to plus or minus of the capacitor?

I assume to minus.

Comment: What makes you think plus would connect to minus? [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Batteries in series are + to -. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: But batteries in parallel are + to +.

Comment: It has nothing to do with parallel or series connection, it is due to a fact that terminal of a cap attached to a + of a battery will become + itself.

Comment: Just recently you said it has to do with series connection. Now it isn’t? VTC as unclear.

Comment: My bad, it has nothing to do with series or parallel connection.

Comment: Both answers are right.

Comment: @SimonB No they're not. Series or parallel is totally irrelevant, what matters is that + side of the cap is always connected to + of the source.

Comment: I fully admit the mistake i made in the assumption. Also, you can call it 'in parallel' if you like, what i meant is when all you have in the circuit is a source and an empty cap, you cannot talk of series or parallel, it is both and none so these terms are meaningless, just like Tesla coil primary LC tank, when the gap fires it creates a resonant LC circuit. As there is no longer any power supply in that circuit and it oscillates by its own damped oscillations, you can't say if it is parallel or series - it is just a cap connected to a coil. This is the same for both versions of the circuit.

Answer (score 4):

You assume wrong.

You are putting the capacitor in parallel with the bridge, not in series with it.

Plus to plus, minus to minus.  Just like charging a battery.

Comment: It has nothing to do with parallel or series connection, it is due to a fact that terminal of a cap attached to a + of a battery will become + itself.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flwP1e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>